# Nagios check_apt alerting updates available for localhost also on network hosts

Tags: debian, nagios, apt

I have setup nagios to monitor apt on my Debian servers. The problem is that I cannot understand why it is showing me the available number of updates on the local server also for the network servers.

For example I have a server that has 32 packages to update, but I am getting an email alert for 2.

**Services Config:**

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name                  apt-servers
    service_description             APT 
    check_command                   check_apt
    use                             generic-service
    notification_interval           0 ; set > 0 if you want to be renotified
}
```

**Hosts Config**

```
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  apt-servers
        alias           APT servers
        members         vps1, vps2, vps3
        }
```

**Command Config**
From Debian package (untouched)

```
# 'check_apt' command definition
define command{
    command_name    check_apt
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
    }   

# 'check_apt_distupgrade' command definition

define command{
    command_name    check_apt_distupgrade
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt -d
}
```

I have tried to search for documentation on how to configure but failed to fin any extensive one.

Comment: Show us the command definition of your `check_apt`  I would bet the problem is almost certainly there, and not in your service/hostgroup.

Answer (score 2):

To run this plugin on anything other than localhost, you need to run it through an agent of some sort.

For example: `NRPE`, `check_by_ssh` with keys, etc.

(This also applies to memory usage, load, disk usage... anything that's not available via a network socket.)